# Publishing a game based on a famous movie to AppStore

Tags: copyright

Is it allowed to publish a game(or app) based on a famous movie, in which are used real photos of the actors? Will it be rejected because of some author rights issues (US territory) ? If yes, what modifications should be done in order to get approved? I ready looked for this information on apple’s website but could’t find anything related.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it’s copyright infringement

... and possibly trademark infringement.

The right to make a derivative work, which a game based on a movie is, belongs solely to the copyright owner and the people they licence.

> If yes, what modifications should be done in order to get approved?

Everything, needs to be modified. Don’t copy images, names, dialogue, storyline, scenes - basically, come up with your own original work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there some defined steps for getting the permission from copyright owner (in my case it is Warner Bros)? What you would suggest if I don’t want to modify everything because the images/sounds/storyline are the key in the app?

Comment: @Galgometh you can ask, however, if it’s a successful movie, they sell those rights to game studios for millions in some cases. I suggest you make a different app.